# using objective C with swift library syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I am using a library TTGSnackbar in iOS that is written in swift and I have used -Swift.h header to use swift library in objective C.

You can find TTGSnackbar here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/TTGSnackbar/0.2.2/

```
let snackbar = TTGSnackbar(message: "TTGSnackBar !",
                       duration: .middle,
                       actionText: "Action!",
                       actionBlock: { (snackbar) in
        print("Click action!")
})
snackbar.show()
```

I am stuck while calling action block of ttg library. Ho do I achieve that in objective C? So far what I have done is (and it gives me bug at action block):

```
TTGSnackbar *ttg = [[TTGSnackbar alloc]init];
        ttg.actionText = @"OK";
        ttg.message = [[remoteMessage appData]valueForKey:@"message"];
        ttg.actionTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
        ttg.duration = TTGSnackbarDurationForever;
        ttg.actionBlock(TTGSnackbar * _Nonnull^{})
        [ttg show];
```

I wnat TTGSnackbar to dismiss on click of OK button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `actionBlock` like this:

```
[ttg setActionBlock:^(TTGSnackbar * snackbar) {
    NSLog(@"snackbar action");
}];
```